# how should i insert a dynamic radar chart in word document by c# programming

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

i want to have a radar chart in a word document which is the exported report from some data in my web application. 
i need this radar chart to show some figure from my data . 
for exporting this word document and handling it's contents , i'm using Microsoft.Office.Inter-op.Word . 
i get some syntax error by using chart and inline-shape class and interface.
my problem is in the (applying the radar chart 1) part in the code and i get error there.

```
//word app
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
winword.Visible = false;


//Temlate info
string templateName = "\\ATM_Template_V1.0.docx";
templatePath = templatePath + templateName;


//word file
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = winword.Documents.Add(templatePath);


//applying the radar chart 1
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape chart1=document.InlineShapes[1];
if (document.InlineShapes[1].HasChart) ; //error


//closing word document
document.SaveAs(filePath);
document.Close();
document = null;



//finishing word application
winword = null;


//kill the process
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("winword");
foreach (Process proc in procs)
proc.Kill();
```

i don't know how to have a dynamic radar chart or any other chart in my report .
please help

Comment: You may be able to create the chart with MSChart, export the image and insert into the word doc.

Comment: i want to have a chart in my word document (as the exported report) . not separated !

Comment: i search for a tutorial about ms chart. and also i download it's exe file and install it.

Comment: but i don't understand how can it help me!

Comment: MSChart is in the data tab of the toolbox.. [Here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETChart-9e45b8d1) is a tutorial.

Comment: so... how can i have it in my word report?

Comment: Save as png and import as image

Comment: Atena, Does the template you're using to "add" the document already contain a chart? Or does this template contain other objects (`InlineShapes`)? What is the error you get? Microsoft Office does have a charting engine available as part of the interop. And Radar charts are available. In order to have a dynamic chart in an Office file, the data MUST be in an Excel workbook. For Word, inserting a chart object embeds the Excel workbook and chart as part of the Word document. I suggest you start by using Insert/Chart *as a user* in order to see what the functionality can do and how it works.

Comment: i wanna use Microsoft.office.interop.word.chart chart1 = document.chart[1]. (exactly like the time i wanna fill a table dynamically in a word) .my word report contain a radar chart. i mean that my template contain a radar chart and by code , i want to update it and get it some data. but i can't .(because of the syntax error in the first line i said).  can you please give me some example or link for reading and something like this? i have no idea how should i use excel for having this chart in word.

Comment: You still haven't answered my questions. Without that information no one can know why your code isn't working.

Comment: Dear Cindy ... can i have a email address or something else which can connect me to you? i wanna send you my code and see what is the problem if you can help me ...

Comment: because i'm new here and don't know how to show you my code or connect you easier